# Node: Socket io require.resolve is not a function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I'm surprised that googling this does not give me any results. Anyway here's my problem when using `socket.io`:

[image]

When I check further, it was from socket.io index.js source file (line 28) that's causing problem:

`var clientSource = read(require.resolve('socket.io-client/socket.io.js'), 'utf-8');`

So require.resolve() is not a function, I suspect at first it was my node version but no, I have updated to latest and it still persists.

I'm using browserify and gulp to generate the app file.

Anyone has a a fix on this? Thanks

Comment: try updating your socketio version

Comment: You're building `socket.io.js` yourself?  Show us your browserify command.

Comment: @Brad: No I'm not building it myself, I include like a module

Comment: @A-0-: Already latest

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`browserify` implementation of `require` doesn't have `resolve` method.

for obvious reasons, you can't run `socket.io` server inside browser. If you really want a socket.io client, you should require `socket.io-client` (readme says it is browserify-compatible).

Comment: So, this is for client? The socket.io to inject in express server itself should still like `require('socket.io');` right?

Answer (score 3):

To use socket.io in the browser install the client lib:

```
npm install socket.io-client --save
```

it can be imported with:

```
var io = require('socket.io-client');
```