# Using proxyquire in a browserify factor bundle

Tags: javascript, typescript, browserify, tsify, factor-bundle

Stuck with this one.

I am using [laravel elxir](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/elixir) with [tsify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsify) to generate my js. I run the typescript through factor-bundle to split common js modules into a seperate files. I don't think though that will be a problem in this case because everything is in a spec.js

spec.ts

```
/// <reference path="../../../typings/index.d.ts" />
import "jasmine-jquery";
// @start widgets
import "./widgets/common/widget-factory/test";
```

factory-widget/index.ts

```
export class WidgetFactory {
 .... this contains a require call to browser.service which i need to mock
}
```

factory-widget/test.ts

```
...
import {WidgetFactory} from "./index";
const proxyRequire =  require("proxyquire");

  it("should output the factory items", ()=> {

        proxyRequire('./widgets/browser.service/index',{
            "@global": true,
   });
}
```

browser-service.ts

```
...
export class BrowserService implements IBrowserService{
 //details
}
```

Getting an error `Uncaught TypeError: require.resolve is not a function` on line 262.

[Here is the code ( yeah it's over 20,000 lines )](https://jsfiddle.net/sidouglas/5s03g4je/) how else are you supposed to debug this stuff . ¯_(ツ)_/¯

I've looked at [Stubbing with proxyquire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29939643/stubbing-with-proxyquire). I am not holding my breath getting an answer on this one.

Edit: 06-09-2016
Proxquire is needed to overide the require call in the boot method of the WidgetFactory class

In factory-widget/index.ts:

```
boot(output = true):any {
        let required = {};

        if (this._sorted.length) {
            this._sorted.forEach((key)=> {
                if (output) {
                    console.log(`${this._path}${key}/index`);
                    // this is where is need to overide the call to require. 
                    required[key] = require(`${this._path}${key}/index`);
                }
            });

            this._sorted.forEach((key)=> {

                let dependencies = {},
                    module = this._factory[key];

                if (module.hasOwnProperty(this.dependencyKey)) {
                    module[this.dependencyKey].map((key)=> {
                        dependencies[_.camelCase(key)] = this.isService(module) ? new required[key] : key;
                    });
                }

                if (this.isTag(module)) {
                    if (output) {
                        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ()=> {
                            riot.mount(key, dependencies);
                        });
                    }
                    //console.log(key,dependencies);
                }
                else {

                }
            })
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't think this will work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26451849/node-socket-io-require-resolve-is-not-a-function browserify doesn't have require.resolve is not a function. Getting that error now.

Answer (score 0):

I've added a [`proxyquireify`](https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquireify) example to the [`tsify`](https://github.com/TypeStrong/tsify/tree/master/examples/proxyquireify) GitHub repo. It's based on the simple [example](https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquireify#example) in the `proxyquireify` `README.md`.

The significant parts are the re-definition of `require` to call `proxyquire` in `foo-spec.ts`:

```
const proxyquire = require('proxyquireify')(require);
require = function (name) {
    const stubs = {
        './bar': {
            kinder: function () { return 'schokolade'; },
            wunder: function () { return 'wirklich wunderbar'; }
        }
    };
    return proxyquire(name, stubs);
} as NodeRequire;
```

and the configuration of the `proxyquire` plugin in `build.js`:

```
browserify()
    .plugin(tsify)
    .plugin(proxyquire.plugin)
    .require(require.resolve('./src/foo-spec.ts'), { entry: true })
    .bundle()
    .pipe(process.stdout);
```

If you build the `bundle.js` and run it under Node.js, you should see that the message written to the console includes strings returned by the functions in the stubbed `./bar` module.

Comment: Thanks for this, but as in the question I am using laravel elixir which is wrapper around gulp. I gave up and ended up dependency injecting require  from the spec. Was the easiest way to overwrite it for mocking purposes.

Comment: No worries. I spent a little bit of time looking into it, as `proxyquireify` seemed like a useful tool.